# Notification не отображает картинку

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Notification уведомление не на всех телефона подтягивает картинку. использую
`.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)`
и на большинства телефонах работает. а вот на одном телефоне и в эмуляторе нет - просто белый кружок.
пробовал подтягивать картинки из `drawable`. форма иконок меняется - а вот внутри по прежнему белым бело.

Что не так? Может есть какие-то определенные размеры?

**UPDATE:**

На этих телефонах получается выводит векторные изображения. Но что делать с растровым?
Одни телефоны принимают `.setSmallIcon()` в виде растра, а другие нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иконка с прозрачным фоном?

Comment: @AndrewGrow да.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404916/android-notification-icon-is-a-white-circle

Comment: @AndrewGrow нет, это не помогло. у меня получилось вывести вектор. но как быть с растровым изображением?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что я узнал? Некоторые телефоне не могут отобразить цветной Notification (только белый), кто-то может, кто-то вместо заданной ставить иконку самого приложения.
Я нашел выход для себя.

через `ImageAssets` создать `Action Bar and Tab Icons` с именем `ic_action_name` и выбрать для него цвет. кто может - покажет его, кто нет - будет серым.

```
 Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_action_name);
```

а в конструкторе Notification

```
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_name)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
```